# Cant unmount my Hard Drive!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, drive, unmount

So I really want to dual boot windows xp and Ubuntu. But when I enter the installer for xp it says not enough partition space or something...

So I go to unmount it and this is what I get...

josiah@josiah-Compaq-CQ58-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda2

umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

I dont know what to do! I dont know what those processes are and where they are located!
I am a linux newb so this might be really easy to fix but PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to unmount the very Linux filesystem partition which is obviously impossible because Linux can not unmount itself.

To know your partitions you can use:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

But to dual boot, you really do not need to rely on Windows. Just install Ubuntu. It checks your filesystem and if it find enough space, it will ask you in a nice graphical mode if you want it to be installed alongside windows. Then it gives you grub (OS selector) to decide which OS you want to boot from.